# How to backup RPI when file directory is on USB device

Tags: backup

Because I'm running a server, I moved my Pi's file directory to a USB device using [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=351659#p351659) tutorial, which means that I'm booting from an SD card, but all of the stuff I need is in a USB drive.  How can I back up both my SD card and my USB so that I can save all of my settings if something crashes.  Better yet, is there a way to backup my files via FTP or SSH?

Answer (score 1):

Your server most likely runs headless, remote access is via `ssh`.

USB drive and SD card are both known to your system via fstab. So, it actually doesn't matter what they are, physically.

If you want a simple method with a small footprint, please consider [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Note that `rsync` plays nice via ssh, you probably want exactly that to backup your data to another remote machine. Authentification can be realized via **ssh-keys**.

Comment: Could you suggest any tutorial I could follow to accomplish this?  I'm more or less a newcomer to linux and I'm not very confident on doing something like this without help.

Comment: This may help http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13611/using-rsync-to-backup-pi