# Using rsync to backup Pi

Tags: raspbian, backup, macos

I decided to implement a `rsync` strategy similar to that suggested by @goldilocks https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5492/8697

BACKGROUND I have a Pi, which is mainly used headless via `ssh` or `VNC`. I also run `netatalk` on the Pi so I can mount the `home` directory in `Finder` (or [QuollEyeTree](http://binnie.id.au/QuollEyeTree.html)). I want to run the backup on my Mac.

I have a `rsync-exclude.txt` which contains:-

```
/proc/*
/sys/*
/dev/*
/boot/*
/tmp/*
/run/*
/mnt/*
```

and run my `rsync` with the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to synchronise Pi files to backup
rsync -av --delete-during --exclude-from=bin/rsync-exclude.txt pi@MYPINAME.local:/ /Volumes/Data/PiBackup
```

I encountered a number of issues, which are my actual questions (if anyone can help):-

1. @goldilocks used `rsync -aEv ...` I tried this and got

   `rsync: on remote machine: --extended-attributes: unknown option`
   This confused me; `man rsync` listed `E`. I know extended attributes are not often used on Linux, but OS X makes extensive use of them, and if I list files on the Pi home directory (mounted on my Mac) I can see them, and list values.
2. Initially I used `--exclude-from=~/bin/rsync-exclude.txt`, but `rsync` could not find it. I discovered that `scp` assumes all paths are relative to the home directory, and apparently so does `rsync`; although this does not seem to be documented.
3. The script will not delete files from the backup when deleted on the Pi.

   `IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion`

I assume this is related to file permissions. The backup files are all owned by my Mac user.
I wonder what would happen if/when I try to restore the system files.

Comment: Instead of deleting, consider using rdiff-backup

Comment: Try with `--progress` save the output and search for the IO error mentioned.

Comment: My `man rsync` calls `-E` "preserve executability" -- I've stopped using that after someone pointed out `-a` includes `-p`, "preserve permissions" (and executability is part of permissions).  Of course that's not a solution to the problem and it would be the OSX implementation of rsync that you are using (if they are different)...just read user1133275's answer and sounds like they are.

Comment: [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/ "rsnapshot") takes most of the horror out of the rsync command line for periodic backups. I've had it running quietly on my Raspberry Pis for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why people are suddenly answering this question more than a year after it was asked.

For the record, I decided that rsync to Mac OS X wasn't going to work (due to different `rsync` options, but more importantly as with different users on OS X the permissions were not retained).

I now use the procedure outlined in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28087/8697 - this backs up my Pi to an external HDD.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using 2 different `rsync --version`s, the one from apple thinks you want `copy extended attributes, resource forks`, and the one from Debian thinks you want `preserve executability`. if you want the former use `-X` instead, and if you want the latter just don't use `-E` as it is redundant because it's part of `-p` which is part of `-a` so there is no need for you to use it because you are using `-a`. If you want a more compatable rsync you can get one from macports/homebrew/etc.
2. Regarding "paths are relative", they are not. It's just that rsync is not expanding `~` to `$HOME` so you can use absolute `--exclude-from=/Users/me/bin/rsync-exclude.txt`, relative `--exclude-from=bin/rsync-exclude.txt`, or pre evaluated variables `--exclude-from=$(ls -1 ~/bin/rsync-exclude.txt)`.
3. To permit deleting files, run the script as root or prefixed with sudo, or without the `-a` (equivalent to `-rlptgoD`) (use `-rlt` instead)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that `--exclude-from=bin/rsync-exclude.txt` means the path is **relative** to your current directory and that `--exclude-from=~/bin/rsync-exclude.txt` is an absolute path - always targeting the `bin` folder in your home directory.

So, either you have to put the file with your exclusions in a directory relative to your backup script, or, better, put it in some appropriate directory and give an absolute path.

Hope this could at least minimize some problems with the exclusions.

**Note**

Just wondering why you put a `*.txt` file in a directory named `bin` ... this is somewhat confusing... at least to me.

Comment: If you tried that with OSX you would know rsync will not work with ~/

Comment: Sorry, never used OS X - at least he has the chance to replace `~/` with `/home/username`