# copy sd card through terminal

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, retropie, terminal, backup

I'm trying to back up my  retro pie SD card in case of corruption, but Retro pie does not have a desktop environment, so can't use the sd card copier tool. Is there some terminal command to do this? I'm using a raspberry pi4 and the official retro pie image.

Comment: I could use a little more clarification for these answers.

Comment: I agree on the "more clarification needed" point.  I don't know what "retro pi" is (another clever marketing gimmick from the House of Pi?), BUT you might consider `image-utils` as a potential solution. I've posted [several answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A83790+image-utils) here that proposed `image-utils` as a backup solution - [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109364/83790) in response to a long-standing question that has other solutions you may find useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html), this applies also for creating an image of an SDD, USB, ... and restoring it

It's best to unmount the drive you're going to copy. In case of the SD-card, remove the SD-card from the RPi and put it into a card reader. Don't mount.

The basic command is this:

```
dd if=input_file of=output_file status=progress
```

Use `lsblk` to determine the name of the drive, eg. `/dev/sdb`

So if your SD-card/USB/SDD is on `/dev/sdb`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/path/to/folder/backup.img status=progress
```

to restore

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/folder/backup.img of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

Don't output the file onto the same SD card. Use another drive. You can use the block size `BS` to use bigger blocks. Eg. `BS=4M`

If you want, you can pipe the image directly into a compressed file.
Eg. using `gzip`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb | gzip > /path/to/folder/backup.img.gz
```

To restore:

```
gunzip -c /path/to/folder/backup.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

Taken from the [question](http://how-to-dd-a-remote-disk-using-ssh-on-local-machine-and-save-to-a-local-disk) over at unix.stackexchange. To backup from your computer over ssh without removing the SD-card

```
ssh user@remote "dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 -" | dd of=image.gz
```

Comment: As far as I understand the OP like to backup the running system itself. This isn't possible with `dd`.

Comment: @Ingo It's an SD card he wants to back up. Put it into a card reader, et viola

Comment: @Swedgin Have you tested this?

Comment: @UNKNOWN yes, this is a known command in linux (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html).

Comment: @Swedgin Is "/dev/sda" The location of my raspberry pi's SD card?

Comment: @UNKNOWN I've updated my post with more information. Let me know if it's clear

Comment: @Swedgin I  want to know if this simply will take the information off the pi, and copy it to an SD card that I can swap with the one in the pi.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can I flash that image with Etcher?

Comment: @UNKNOWN, yes, this will basically copy the whole SD-card to an image the same size, including partition table. So restoring this to an SD-card the same size or bigger will get you the exact same system you've backup'd. I use the same method for my SDD on my laptop.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, you can do a `dd` of the running system itself but you do not get a consistent image because of dynamically changed files during backup which may break the restored image.

Comment: I use quite old Raspberry Pi. In my case SD-card was mounted as readonly filesystem so there was no need to unmount. Card was not available as `/dev/sd*`. But I found it as `/dev/mmcblk0` using `lsblk -p`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look through [Using rsync to backup Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13611/using-rsync-to-backup-pi)

You need to set the exclusions to include where the roms are stored.

I would question why not backup the rom files though?  Restoring the machine WHEN (not if) the SD card fails will take significantly longer if you have to download / find all the rom files again...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is on command in either Linux or the RetroPi setup to achieve this but you can use either :

https://github.com/crcerror/RetroPie-Simple-Backup-Script

OR

https://github.com/kallsbo/BASH-RaspberryPI-System-Backup

There may be other scripts or options available if you do a web search. In Linux at least Bash scripts are your friends :D

Comment: @ Etescartz Sorry, but I want to copy the SD card not the roms.